# I am getting this error :ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error in window 10 while coonecting to sql plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I keep on getting this error . I have corrected ora.listner file as mentioned in other answer of similar problem in stack overflow and I was able to login  too but problem start again when I open my window 10 again today.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PFFr.png)

[listner.ora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGy9f.png)

[Result of lsnrctl status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AQgI.png)

[open listner.ora file without editing and saved it and restart  i am able to connect now. Every time i have to do this to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lm22.png)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the Oracle service hasn't started. Open up powershell and check it with

```
get-service OracleService*
```

If it says it's stopped then you can do

```
get-service OracleService* | start-service
```

If it has started then your `oracle_sid` environment variable hasn't been set or your `oracle_home` isn't correct.

Comment: i just open listner.ora and saved it and restart and it start working . Also I checked my service is running. I did not write anything over there listner.ora file.

Comment: Your listener.ora file has nothing to do with the local connection attempt you tried.

Comment: means I am able to connect once I restart the window idk how? I have edited the pic of result of the lsnrtcl status after I restart.

Comment: Next time you reboot your pc and have the same issue. Check what the status of your Oracle service is. When the one pointed to by your oracle_sid isn't running, you get that error, you can also get the error if you've set oracle_home and it's not correct for the oracle_sid. There is no relation with the listener whatsoever.

Comment: you were right it says oracle service stop whenever I get this error. Did the get-service OracleService* | start-service in windows shell and its work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortnately, I cannot see where you showed the actual sqlplus command, just a screen shot that picks up *after* sqlplus gets control.  But I find the near 100% of the time I see this error, it is because sqlplus is started *without* specifying a connect descriptor. Doing so means you are asking for a *local* connection, so the listener, nor any other TNS component is not involved at all.  Instead, sqlplus tries to make a *local* (in memory) connection to the *running instance* that is specified by the environment variable ORACLE_SID:

TNS Connection:

```
G:\scripts>sqlplus scott/tiger@edstest

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Oct 27 15:46:01 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Oct 27 2020 15:45:42 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

local connection, check ORACLE_SID first

```
G:\scripts>echo %ORACLE_SID%
edstest

G:\scripts>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Oct 27 15:47:32 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Oct 27 2020 15:46:01 -05:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

Local connection with ORACLE_SID not set, or improperly set:

```
G:\scripts>set ORACLE_SID=FUBAR

G:\scripts>echo %ORACLE_SID%
FUBAR

G:\scripts>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Oct 27 15:48:57 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name: ^C
G:\scripts>set ORACLE_SID=

G:\scripts>echo %ORACLE_SID%
%ORACLE_SID%

G:\scripts>sqlplus scott/tiger

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Oct 27 15:49:59 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error


Enter user-name:
```

And there's your error.