# ORA-12560 error when Jenkins runs script that connects to oracle on agent machine

Tags: oracle, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So I have a script file that is on my agent machine that runs a series of database upgrades. When executing the script manually on the machine, it works fine. When attempting to get Jenkins to run the script, I get ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error.

This was working last week before I configured Jenkins to run as a service, but I am not sure if that has anything to do with it. The Jenkins service is configured to use the localadmin account, the same account I use when running the script manually. Stopping the service and launching the agent connection script via the command line did not fix the issue though.

Is there some configuration I am missing? Our VM server also had maintenance last weekend, but I am not sure why that would break anything.

**Update** - I think I discovered a workaround for this. I still think the issue has to do with running Jenkins as a service and how something fundamentally is changing. If I try to run my scripts that launch connections to oracle normally, they fail. If I use powershell Invoke-Command -ComputerName agent machine -ScriptBlock {command} this works as expected.

Hopefully this can help anyone who stumbles across this question.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your database and network listener are running? If so, then it sounds like the shell in which the script is now running is probably not configured with the right $ORACLE_HOME and/or $PATH variables. If you're not already, make sure you set those in the script itself, and fully qualify the path to any executable files called in the script just to be sure.

Comment: I queried the environment variables in powershell both locally and through a jenkins instance of powershell. They all look the same. I queried the status of my oracle listener through Jenkins as well and it says it is running. I am at a loss.

Comment: Is this on windows? If so, check that there are not multiple oracle_home/bin in your PATH.

Comment: It is on windows. Our environments are set with separate server and client homes for oracle with no oracle_home/bin in the path.

I have tested on a machine that was never configured to run Jenkins as a windows service and it does not get the ORA-12560 error. This seems specific to however the behavior is changed once this is configured. I don't know of any documentation that explains the differences.

Comment: What does your sqlplus connect string look like? e.g. `sqlplus user/pw@instance ...`? [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64561481/i-am-getting-this-error-ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adapter-error-in-window-10-whil) for some troubleshooting ideas.

Comment: sqlplus -s username/password   This generates the failed error.  If I manually add @sid then it seems to work. However, if I also query the SID from jenkins, it is correct.

Comment: Not specifying the `@tns_alias` requires that `ORACLE_SID` be set as an environment variable, *and* that the database be running on the same host. If you're connecting over a network, then you *must* include `@tns_alias` in the connect string so that sqlplus can lookup the details in tnsnames.ora, or a complete fast connect string with host, port, and service_name.

Comment: I am definitely not an expert in this, but all Jenkins does is launch a local batch script that then runs subsequent scripts. Those scripts all live on the local machine where the database is.  On top of that, isn't running a script on a Jenkins agent actually running that on the machine itself and not through the network? As I mentioned, this worked through Jenkins before setting it as a service.